# populate jQuery UI accordion with xml, binding problem

Tags: jquery, xml, dom, binding, accordion

I am populating jQuery accordion from simple xml file, I can get my data and append it as html to simulate accordion markup. Then I call for accordion, it won't work!

I guess the problem is binding newly created data to DOM, I have tried .live() and .delegate with no success.

How should I proceed?

Here is simplified example of my code (sorry that some of the names and comments are in finnish :-)) here is the link http://www.equstom.fi/hanuri.html

```
$('#valitsija').click(function() {
 $.get('http://www.equstom.fi/kurssit.xml', function(data) {
    $('#accordion').empty();
  $(data).find('Kurssi').each(function() {
  var $kurssi = $(this);
  var html = '<div>';
  html += '<h3><a href="#">' + $kurssi.find('KurssinNimi').text()  + '</a></h3>';
  html += '<div>' + $kurssi.find('KurssiKuvaus').text() + '</div>';
  html += '</div>';
  $('#accordion').append($(html));
  }); 
 });
});
```

/* **********************     haetaankurssit loppu   ************** ********/
   // Accordion
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });

```
http://www.equstom.fi/hanuri.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the two lines below I added (with comments). You need to destroy and then recreate the accordion.

```
    $('#valitsija').click(function() {
    $.get('http://www.equstom.fi/kurssit.xml', function(data) {

        //you need to destroy the accordion first
        $('#accordion').accordion("destroy");
        $('#accordion').empty();

        $(data).find('Kurssi').each(function() {

            var $kurssi = $(this);
            var html = '<div>';
            html += '<h3><a href="#">' + $kurssi.find('KurssinNimi').text()  + '</a></h3>';
            html += '<div>' + $kurssi.find('KurssiKuvaus').text() + '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            $('#accordion').append($(html));

        }); 

        //you need to re-make the accordion
        $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });
    });
});
```

I would suggest storing the #accordion into a variable so you don't have to keep searching for it. This is called caching. (I know its not your question, but figured I'd offer this suggestion anyways). Something like this:

```
$('#valitsija').click(function() {
    $.get('http://www.equstom.fi/kurssit.xml', function(data) {

        var acc = $('#accordion');
        //you need to destroy the accordion first
        acc.accordion("destroy");
        acc.empty();

        $(data).find('Kurssi').each(function() {

            var $kurssi = $(this);
            var html = '<div>';
            html += '<h3><a href="#">' + $kurssi.find('KurssinNimi').text()  + '</a></h3>';
            html += '<div>' + $kurssi.find('KurssiKuvaus').text() + '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            acc.append($(html));

        }); 

        //you need to re-make the accordion
        acc.accordion({ header: "h3" });
    });
});
```

[Proof that it works](http://www.mattseanhull.com/so/kurssit.htm)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, I have been up all night trying to solve this, but I was solving the wrong problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an XML to jQuery Accordion utility last night and I thought I'd share it with you all here. Any feedback is appreciated.

http://lytsp33d.com/xml-to-jquery-accordion/

Best regards,
Zach